# How should verb goes with "let" be in past tenses?

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-tense, let

How should verb goes with "let" be in past tenses?

- **Present tense:** let's go; let me see
- **Past tense:** let's went? let me saw?

I'm unable to search for any information about this. It seems like *let* will never be used in a past tense sentence

Comment: You could use the present tense in dialog: *He said, "Let's go!"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The past form of  let is let.

Let-let-let.

It is also used in the imperative.

**Let me  see it**

You can not have  past forms  for imperative sentences.

However you can say:

> **My  principal let me leave  early  yesterday**.
>
> **He let  me  see the  picture  yesterday**

Negative sentences:

> **The principal did not let me leave early yesterday**
>
> **He did not let me see the picture yesterday**

Comment: Why can't imperative sentences have past forms? Also, how do you convert the two examples ("My principal let me...", "He let me...") to past forms? Do "leave" and "see" change to "left" and "saw"?

Comment: @Ooker - Those two examples are already in the past tense. If they were present tense, *let* would be *lets* (no apostrophe), and you'd need to remove *yesterday*.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a "past tense" for ***Let's go, Let me see*** - which technically speaking are ***imperative*** requests / commands / suggestions, with implied subject "you".

The nearest equivalents I think of are ***We should have gone, You should have let me see***, because the "present tense" versions are equivalent to ***We should go, You should let me see***.

Comment: Sure. ***We let go*** is "ambiguous", in that it could be Present or Past (which I guess makes it a "degenerate" verb). But both OP's examples are imperatives, so I don't think it's really *necessary* to cover other contexts. Having said that, I agree with JVL's answer as well (which of course ***I've*** upvoted! :) It's an interesting question as to whether we should understand ***Let's go!*** as a "first person **plural** imperative" though - if/when my currently dicky broadband connection ungums itself I might look to see if that specific point has ever been addressed on ELU.

Answer (score 1):

- **Let's go**.

**let's + a verb in English is an imperative**. Imperatives are only in the present tense. The meaning is: Let's leave this place or Let's do [something].

- **Let me** see. means to allow someone to see something or it is an idiom meaning: Let me see if something another person says works or is right in a context.

The verb let is the same in all tenses:

They let us go to the movies. [both simple present AND simple past]
They have let us go to the movies. [this week, this month, recently, this year etc.]
They are letting us go to the movies.

There are other verbs that do not change in English: put, set, hit, cost, hurt, shut, quit, split, and spread.

I know of no language that has imperatives in other tenses. The nature of the imperative is that it applies to the present.

"My principal let me [do something]."  **can be simple present or simple past. Only a specific context will tell you which it is.**

to let go is also a phrasal verb: Let it go. [disregard it or let something loose, like a fish you catch]